# how to add a database constraint 18 or above

Tags: sql

i have create a table and I need to add a database constraint "A customer with an age under 18 cannot rent a movie rated “18 or above”." How do I use SQL to add this in my table

Comment: Can you share a little bit more about the structure of your tables? It sounds like you just need a column with a age constraint that is either a boolean for `adult` and check it against that. i.e. `select * from movies where adult in (0)` would mean any non-adult movies, where as `select * from movies where adult in (1,0)` would mean any adult or non-adult movies

Comment: PLease tag with database and table definition

Comment: Please add the table script so that others understand what exactly you are trying to do, what are the fields etc. Also tag you question with database, SQL etc for wider reach

Answer (score 0):

You can use a trigger. When you want to enter information in the system to order a movie, do not allow the user to create a record if the age is less than the minimum required.

The following code snippet implements this scenario completely.

```
CREATE TABLE Customers
(
ID int identity,
FirstName nvarchar(100),
LastName nvarchar(100),
Age int,
primary key(ID))


CREATE TABLE Films
(
ID int identity,
FilmName nvarchar(100),
MinimumAge int,
primary key(ID))


CREATE TABLE OrderFilms
(
ID int identity,
CustomerID int,
FilmID int,
primary key(ID),
foreign key(CustomerID) references Customers,
foreign key(FilmID) references Films)


create trigger trigger_for_insert_into_OrderFilms
On OrderFilms
For Insert
AS
Declare @film int
Declare @customer int

Declare @filmage int
Declare @customerage int

set @film = (SELECT top 1 FilmID FROM inserted)
set @customer = (SELECT top 1 CustomerID FROM inserted)

set @filmage = (SELECT MinimumAge FROM Films WHERE ID = @film)
set @customerage = (SELECT Age FROM Customers WHERE ID = @customer)

IF(@filmage > 18 AND @customerage < 18)
BEGIN
PRINt 'ERROR, CUSTOMER AGE THE CUSTOMER IS YOUNG'
RollBack
END
```